# Import multiple images in Excell in certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

Can please someone tell me is there a possibility to import multiple images into Excell into certain cells?
For example, I need a macro where I can select images from folder and then import them but in a certain order:

```
1st picture - B2
2nd picutre - D2
3rd picture - B4
4th picutre - D4
5th picture - B6
6th picutre - D6
7th picture - B8
8th picutre - D8
```

Or if that can't be done, at lease to import them in two columns, B and D,

Thanks in advance!

Zoran

Comment: [ask] and [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize the width and height of your cell accordingly before running the sub because the picture size will resize according to cell size

update: modify sheet name accordingly
the code will insert by block of 8 pics

```
    Sub Insert_Picture()
    Dim myPicture As Variant
    Dim lLoop As Long, cl As Long, rw As Long, rwcheck As Long, blockcheck As Long
    Dim PlaceAtCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    cl = 2
    
    myPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        ("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png),*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif *.png", , _
        "SELECT FILE(S) TO IMPORT", MultiSelect:=True)
    If VarType(myPicture) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "NO FILES SELECTED"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws.Cells(2, 2) = "pic holder" Then
        rw = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 3
    Else
        rw = 2
    End If

    If IsArray(myPicture) Then
        For lLoop = LBound(myPicture) To UBound(myPicture)
                        
            If blockcheck Mod 8 = 0 Then rw = rw + 1
            
            Set PlaceAtCell = ws.Cells(rw, cl)
            ws.Cells(rw, cl) = "pic holder"
        
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
                 Filename:=myPicture(lLoop), _
                 LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                 SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                 Left:=PlaceAtCell.Left, _
                 Width:=PlaceAtCell.Width, _
                 Top:=PlaceAtCell.Top, _
                 Height:=PlaceAtCell.Height)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            End With
            
            If cl = 2 Then
                cl = cl + 2
            Else
                cl = 2
            End If
            
            rwcheck = rwcheck + 1
            
            If rwcheck >= 2 Then
                rw = rw + 2
                rwcheck = 0
            End If
        blockcheck = blockcheck + 1
        Next lLoop
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just one more question, what if I want my next sequence of pictures to go from cell B11, D11, B13, D13.. Is there a way to do that? To skip two rows after first sequence?

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić  you want to insert starting at row 11? just change the initial value of `rw = 2` to `rw = 11`

Comment: No, after I add pictures into 4 rows (2, 4, 6, 8) I want that it continues in row 11, 13, 15, 17.  And then again skip two rows and continues in 20, 22, 24, 26..

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić see updated code above, modify sheet name accordingly the code assumes 8 pictures are inserted everytime the sub is ran

Comment: Thanks, it works like that, but is there a way for that to work if 40 pictures are selected at once?

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić is that your ultimate goal select 40 pictures inserted in blocks of 8?

Comment: Ultimate goal is that code works no matter how many pictures are selected. My collegues are assessors and sometimes they insert 40 pictures, sometimes 100, it depends. But if we have to limit it we can do that on 160 pictures..

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić insert pictures of any number to fit into blocks of 8 as much as possible?

Comment: Yes, exactly? Block of 8 then skip two rows, then another block of 8 then skip two rows again and so on.

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić you could have just stated it in the first place instead of the several days of back and forth

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić see updated code above, just a tip always be specific in stating your ultimate desired goal in the first place when posting questions

Comment: Sorry, I understand. It was supposed to be like we started but my boss changed the initial request.. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @ZoranMaćešić If the provided code successfully addresses your issue, it would be beneficial to designate it as the answer to assist others encountering the same problem